# Can multiply a rotation matrix to rotate the direction vector (vec 3)?

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection, glm-math

I adopted "Separating axis theorem (SAT)" to realize "OBB collision detection".
As shown below, SAT requires three elements.

1. The coordinates (x, y, z) of the midpoint
2. Length of each axis
3. Direction vector of each axis

   [image]

```cpp
// Initialized
SATOBB::SATOBB(glm::vec3 &pos, std::vector<glm::vec3> &dir, glm::vec3 &len)
{
    i_Pos = pos;
    i_Dir = dir;
    i_Len = len;
    m_Dir.push_back(glm::vec3(0,0,0)); // Yeah... I know this strange code.. Thanks for tkausel
}

// i_... is before change, m_... is after change

void SATOBB::update(
glm::mat4 &Rotate, 
glm::mat4 &Trans, 
glm::mat4 &Scale
)
{
    glm::vec3 m_Pos = Trans  * glm::vec4(i_Pos, 1.0f);
    for (int i=0; i<i_Dir.size(); i++){
        glm::vec3 m_Dir = Rotate * glm::vec4(i_Dir, 1.0f);
    }
    glm::vec3 m_Len = Scale  * glm::vec4(i_Len, 1.0f);  
}
```

I think the code for calculating "3." is wrong.
So, please let me know the correct calculation code.

For calculation, I wanted to use the mat4 function, so vec3 is used for "1. & 2.." (For reasons of expediency)

"3." was calculated using vec3.
Is it really enough to multiply the vector by the rotation matrix? 
That is the problem.

Comment: `Is it really enough to multiply the vector by the rotation matrix?` It rotates the vector by the rotation encoded in the matrix, so yes. You might need to normalize if the algorithm expects a unit vector.

Comment: @tkausl    I have not tried unit vectors yet.
I will try to recalculate from now.

Do you think there is no mistake about "1 & 2"

Comment: There is only one direction vector in your code, the image asks for all three. The first three columns of your rotation matrix should contain the three unit vectors in x, y and z direction after rotation was applied.

Comment: @tkausl I made a serious mistake.
I was writing strange code.
You said I need m_Dir for each of the X, Y, and Z axis directions.
At first, I thought surely wrote that. (I forgot to write on the published code sorry ...)
But I was wrong.

Comment: @tkausl That was the initialization stage.
"m_Dir.push_back (glm :: vec 3 (0,0,0)); /// What...???"
Yes, only X was judged.
I am grateful to you for making me realize what is realy important.
Thank you for making!!